# How to change default font in Word 2013 to certain colors for each letter?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, colors

Sorry that this is a bit of a confusing and weird request. Basically, I want to make it so I can easily change any word document to have certain colors for each letter. AKA: all a's are red, b's are blue, etc. I know I can use find and replace and do it one letter at a time, which is what I've been doing, but is there any way to set it as a default or something so I can do it less tediously? Thanks!